# Comment « clause » a-t-il évolué de « conclusion » jusqu'à « proposition » ?

Tags: étymologie, latin

Au départ, je recherchais l'étymologie pour le nom anglais « clause », mais d'après ce qui suit (partie en gras), le changement clé s'est produit entre le latin et le français.

> clause (n.)
>   c. 1200, "a sentence, a brief statement, a short passage," from Old French clause "stipulation" (in a legal document), 12c., from Medieval Latin clausa "conclusion," used in the sense of classical Latin clausula "the end, a closing, termination," also "end of a sentence or a legal argument," from clausa, fem. noun from past participle of claudere "to close, to shut, to conclude" (see [close](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=close&allowed_in_frame=0) (v.)). Grammatical sense is from c. 1300. Legal meaning "distinct condition, stipulation, or proviso" is recorded from late 14c. in English. **The sense of "ending" seems to have fallen from the word between Latin and French.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D'après le [wiktionaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/clause) :

> > **Étymologie**
> >
> > (XIIIe siècle) Du bas latin *clausa*, peut-être via l’ancien occitan *clauza*, de *claudere*, *« clore »*, latin classique *clausula*.
>
> **clause** */kloz/* féminin
>
> > Disposition particulière faisant partie d’un traité, d’un contrat, d’un arrêté, d’une loi ou de tout autre acte public ou particulier, etc.

où [disposition](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/disposition) signifie :

> Chacun des points que règle ou que décide une loi, une ordonnance, un arrêté, un jugement, un arrêt, etc.

et sachant que [clausula](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/clausula) a pour sens :

> - Fin, conclusion.
> - Clausule, fin de phrase.

On peut dire que le sens de clause en français est devenu celui de **disposition particulière** d'un contrat, c'est-à-dire une condition *particulière* du contrat, élaborée par les deux partis et ajoutée **à la fin** de celui-ci, *après* les conditions générales, plus communes, qui sont souvent moins discutées.

C'est ainsi devenu en [anglais](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clause) :

> A separate part of a contract, a will or another legal document.

Avec la même idée de séparation, entre le contrat standard et la partie particulière.